# How to start a job, do something different, and resume it again

Tags: bash, job-control

I want to start a web server via Python. When this succeeds, I want to open the page in the default browser (on macOS, you can do this with the `open` command), and after that, I want to resume the previous script again.

This does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd wwwroot
python3 -m http.server &
open http://0.0.0.0:8000
fg 1
```

I could not use `jobs`, and open the URL, and after that just run the Python script. However, I don't want to reload the page of the URL. Python will continue to run, until stopped by <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

Perhaps, the `open` command needs to have a `sleep` command when Python is not ready yet...

Comment: try `python3 -m http.server && open http://0.0.0.0:8000`. the `&&` means run whatever command is next if the first one succeeds

Comment: Python will stay active until ctrl+c is hit...

Comment: Do the script work as desired when typed interactively line-by-line into the terminal?

Comment: Not completely. It says ` fg: no job control`. Is there a programmatic way to get the job_spec into a variable, so it can be used later, without relying on sed or such? (I have a hard time reading the bash manual)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation, it seems that `$!` is the variable you want. Example:

```
(sleep 1 && open http://0.0.0.0:8000) &
disown $!
python3 -m http.server
```

The `sleep` makes sure (well, very likely at least) the server is up-and-running before the `open` is executed. However, there's still the potential for failure if `python3 -m http.server` takes longer than a second – make certain to document this possibility.

Comment: Too quick. `$!` is the `pid` (process identifier), but fg needs `jobspec`...

Comment: I now do this: `(sleep 1 && open http://0.0.0.0:8000) &; disown $!; python3 -m http.server`

Comment: @doekman That's asking for a race condition, but it might be good enough. Could you post it as an answer so I can delete this one?

Comment: I can just edit this answer (your `$!` contribution made me think of this). What do you mean by "race condition"? I can't see any reason why that should occur. If python is really slow, the `open` statement will cause Safari to say: "could not find server".

Comment: @doekman Yes, that's what I mean. If that's not a problem, why have the wait at all? And if it is, but not a very big one, make _sure_ you document it.